# Passing Variable Between Hooks in Same Class File

Tags: php, hook, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to retrieve a value from one action hook to be displayed in admin page.

```
public function hookActionProductCancel($params)
{
    $this->response = "response";
}
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) {
    $this->context->smarty->assign('response', $this->response);
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/response.tpl');
}
```

I am not receiving the value "response" in response.tpl. Probably a small issue but I am not getting it right at the moment.

Any guidance is truly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just store the response to cookie and clear it before displaying it.

```
public function hookActionProductCancel($params)
{
    // code
    $this->context->cookie->mymodule_response = "response";
    $this->context->cookie->write();
}
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) 
{
    // if no response stored in cookie do nothing
    if (!$this->context->cookie->mymodule_response) {
        return false;           
    }

    // assign response from cookie to smarty then clear response from cookie
    $this->context->smarty->assign('response', $this->context->cookie->mymodule_response);
    unset($this->context->cookie->mymodule_response);

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/response.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, never have I thought of it. Can I just check that for action hooks, I am not able to assign variables to a template?

Comment: Maybe for some hooks you could but it would take some digging into the core to find out which ones because sometimes you don't have the same instance of the module or a redirect might happen in between hooks so you lose assigned variables. Setting/clearing messages through cookie is your best bet, since Prestashop doesn't use native PHP sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to use `this`

```
public function hookActionProductCancel($params)
{
    ..... codes .....
    $this->response = "response";
}

public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) 
{
    $this->context->smarty->assign('response', $this->response);
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/response.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and unfortunately, it is not displaying too. Am I missing something here?

Comment: well that should work... there may be other bugs in other parts of the code, is `hookActionProductCancel` being called before than `hookDisplayAdminOrder`? In other words, are you sure `$this->response` is being set before hitting `hookDisplayAdminOrder`?

Comment: Yes, I have placed the code as such.... hookActionProductCancel is called before hookDisplayAdminOrder. Hmmm.... weird.

Comment: These are public methods... are they being called in the same instance?
Maybe it would help if you posted the code where they are being called

Comment: Sorry, I do not get what do you mean by same instance? I will click on the return button to trigger hookActionProductCancel, thus creating $this->response to assign to hookDisplayAdminOrder... is there anything wrong with my steps?

Comment: When you do `$someObject = new ObjectClassName($parameter);`... that's a new instance of a class. Different instances may contain different data

Comment: I see, I have tested with just the codes - $this->response = "response"; in hookActionProductCancel and try to display from .tpl via hookDisplayAdminOrder... does not seem to work too. I have removed all the other codes to test on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178985/discussion-between-enthu-and-andriusain).