# How to share data between classes in PHP (PrestaShop 1.7 module)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm trying to create a PrestaShop module that will have some logic triggered by an action hook (e.g. *actionValidateOrder*) and temporarily store the result of that logic so it can be used when a display hook is triggered (e.g. *displayHeader*).

In my main class I am assigning a `Store` class singleton to it as `$this` is being passed onto classes triggered on hooks:

```
class PrestashopCustomModule extends Module
{

  public function __construct()
  {

    /* ... */

    parent::__construct();

    $this->customStore = CustomStore::getInstance();

    /* ... */

  }

  /* ... */

  public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
  {
      $hook = new HookActionValidateOrder($this, $this->context);
      $hook->setParams($params);

      return $hook->run();
  }

  public function hookDisplayHeader($params)
  {
      $hook = new HookDisplayHeader($this, $this->context);
      $hook->setParams($params);

      return $hook->run();
  }

}
```

This is the `Store` class:

```
class Store
{

    private static $instance = null;
    private $store = [];

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function push($code)
    {
      $this->store[] = $code;
      return;
    }

    public function get()
    {
      return $this->store;
    }
}
```

When I `$this->module->customStore->push('something')` in the action hook I see it in the array within `Store` but when later the display hook calls `$this->module->customStore->get()` the array within is empty again.

What am I doing wrong, why does it not persist between those calls even though the `Store` class is a singleton?

Comment: Try "$this->context->customStore" instead of "$this->customStore" in constructor

Comment: @MahdiShad That does not seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: I think I might have a reason, looks like the actionValidateOrder hook is triggered on page X, and there's a redirect to another URL Y where the displayHeader hook is triggered. Naturally, that would mean data isn't there by the time I want to read it. I will post an answer when I validate this.

Comment: This should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074452/6271916